# Is copying an .apk into /{system, data}/app sufficient to install an Android application?

Tags: installation, apk, side-loading

If not, what else is done under the covers?

Also, what are the differences when installing applications

- From the android market
- sideloaded from web download
- sideloaded using adb install
- sideloaded using adb push

Comment: Has anyone tried this, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe apps can be installed just by placing them in the appropriate directory.  I'm not sure what the app installer does beyond this copying, if anything.  The Market does update the system's list of apps "linked" to the Market however, so that the Market can check for updates and such.  Apps installed by other means won't show up in the Market's list.